# Allow directory traversal with Apache2

Tags: apache2, penetration-testing, directory-traversal

I'm trying to create a CTF for a project. One of my goals is to set up an Apache web server that allows directory traversal so people attempting my CTF can traverse to my root directory and access a folder containing an encrypted file. I want them to be able to download this file so they can unencrypt it on their machine. However, I don't even know where to start with allowing directory traversal. I've never really used Apache web server before and everything I find online is about *preventing* directory traversal.

I'm using Apache2 on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM.

Answer (score 0):

I got a good enough workaround going.

First, I changed `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` to `"/"` so that the server could access everything in `/` and created an `index.html` file in `/` so that the Apache server would know what to render. Inside of `index.html` is just

```html
    <html><script>location="/home/user/server/index.html";</script>
```

Which render the actual index to display. I did this to make it more obvious that some kind of directory traversal would be done. By doing this, the path that is displayed to visitors is `http://192.168.xx.xx/home/user/server/index.html`.

Then, I added a wildcard directory:

```
  <Directory ~ "/*">
        Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
```

so that the users could enter any folder within the root directory. Now, when anyone visits `192.168.xx.xx` they are routed to `192.168.xx.xx/home/user/server/index.html` and if they enter anything else, say `192.168.xx.xx/etc/passwd` the file will be displayed to them.

I know this isn't true directory traversal, but it is solution enough for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Apache itself will not allow a directory traversal vulnerability to be created. You will need to use something like PHP where you pass a `?file=filename` parameter and use `open()` with that value.

The PHP `open()` function will interpret the `../../` sequences necessary to escape the "intended" directory. However Apache itself will not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

## Minimal example with PHP

1. Also install PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt install php
   ```
2. Clear the web root:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/*
   ```
3. Create `/var/www/html/index.php` with the following content:

   ```php
   <?php
   $p = 'home.php';
   if (isset($_GET['p']))
     $p = $_GET['p'];
   include ($p);
   ?>
   ```
4. Create `/var/www/html/home.php` with the following content:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Read World!</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <a href="?p=home.php">home</a>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Exploit, e. g.:

   ```
   curl http://<IP>/?p=../../../etc/passwd
   ```